# Populate location attribute into text area instead of alert

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I have a function to retrieve my current location based on longitude and latitude.
However, I would like to auto populate a text area (**Populate Here)** with my retrieved results, instead of prompting an alert.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
function getPosition() {

var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  maximumAge: 3600000
}

var watchID = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);

function onSuccess(position) {

  alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
     'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n');
};

function onError(error) {
  alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
}



</script>

 </head>
 <body>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
  <div data-role="header">

        <h1>Test</h1>

</div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form name="bmiform" id="bmiform" action="result.html">
    <input type="hidden" name="actualbmi">


<label for="Location">Location:</label><button onclick = "onSuccess" id = "getPosition">PAN</button>
    <input type="text" name="Location" id="location" placeholder = "Populate Here" (document.getElementsByName('onSuccess')[0].value)>

<br>


<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried already? What is wrong with your code? What error, if any, in dev tools are you getting?

Comment: Remember you can insert code snippets! Which is like having a little tiny jsbin in your question.

Comment: This question is a mess. The code isn't neatly formatted. It switches in and out of JavaScript and HTML as if they were the same language. It'll throw syntax errors which would show up in the Console (and there's no sign of any effort to look at those error messages or ask what they mean). It asks about a "text area" and then uses an `<input>` instead of a `<textarea>`.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry for the mess, I have edited the format of the codes. Do take a look.

Answer (score -1):

So lets say you have a span in html

```
<span id="myspan"><span>
```

In your onSuccess function, you will set the innerHTML of that span, which is is between the opening and closing tags: `<span>`innerHTML is here`</span>`

```
var span = document.getElementById("myspan");
var text = document.createTextNode(position.coords.latitude);
span.innerHTML = ''; // clear existing
span.appendChild(text);
```

You can try adding the longitude yourself.  Good luck!